# Remove amp; from url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, replace

How can I remove **amp;** from this url with htaccess

`http://www.mywebsite.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=144&amp;t=14177`

to make it output like this

`http://www.mywebsite.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=144&t=14177`

Comment: Am i going blind or are they the same url?

Comment: Sorry! question edited. I want to remove amp; in the url.

Answer (score 4):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.*?)\&amp\;([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1&%2 [L,NE,R]
```

This will redirect: `http://domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=144&amp;t=14177&amp;foo=bar` to `http://domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=144&t=14177&foo=bar`

thus converting all `&amp;` to `&`

Answer (score 0):

How about a rewrite rule added to your .htaccess? (Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled in your main apache config).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)&amp;(.*) $1&$2
```

I should be more specific... the above will rewrite the URL and the script `viewtopic.php` will receive the correct query string. The following will redirect the user making the URL appear correctly in their browser.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)&amp;(.*) $1&$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, getting closer. It works if i type the url `http://www.mywebsite.com/forum/viewtopic.php&amp;` but if I use the full url with F= and T= included nothing happens (this: `http://www.mywebsite.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=144&amp;t=14177`)

Any ideas how to rewrite it with the full url?. I'm noob at this..

Comment: I removed the string style=54 earlier with this code `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^style=[0-9]+&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [L,R=301]` it removes `style=54&` in the url `http://www.mywebsite.com/forum/viewtopic.php?style=54&f=144&t=14177` maybe some edits could solve this problem with amp;...