# HTACCESS to Remove /amp/ from the end of a URL

Tags: .htaccess

/amp/ was showing up at the end of all of my URLS incorrectly. I have fixed it, but I now have a mess. I have many urls with /amp/ on search that I need to redirect to a url with the /amp/ removed from the end. How would I do this with .htaccess?

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp/?$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

And it does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework?

Comment: Can you please explain more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove amp; from url with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460924/remove-amp-from-url-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache Web Server, you can use below rule for redirecting your all AMP urls to NON-AMP version.

**Example**
`https://example.com/permalink/amp/` to `https://example.com/permalink/`

```
# Redirect from AMP to non-AMP path
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
```

I hope this helps.