# Redirect from AMP URLs to Real URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to convert old links amp links to basic topics in wordpress
Via the .htaccess file
I tried this code but it did not work

```
#Redirect old AMP URLs
RewriteRule (.*)/AMP$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]

#Redirect old AMP URLs
RewriteRule (.*)/amp/$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

I want Redirect from

- http://example.com/news/55/amp/

to

- http://example.com/news/55/

Comment: Both urls are identical. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes the links have been corrected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove amp; from url with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460924/remove-amp-from-url-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, for redirecting your all AMP URLs to NON-AMP (Canonical) version, you may use below rule -

```
# Redirect from AMP to non-AMP path
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
```

Source: https://www.gulshankumar.net/fix-404-on-amp/
Disclaimer: I am author.