# Remove /amp from URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to use .htaccess to remove /amp from a certain URL structure. I have incoming links that look like this:

https://domain/store/amp and https://domain/store/product/amp

In both cases, the /amp on the end results in 404 errors. I just need to get rid of it, because fixing the problem at the source is not currently an option. I intend to put the .htaccess in the /store/ directory path.

I have looked around for similar examples and tried to modify them, but rewrites make my head spin in short order. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove amp; from url with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460924/remove-amp-from-url-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Redirect

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)amp$ /$1
```

Comment: That's beautiful. Thank you so much. It works perfectly.