# .htaccess redirect /amp/ urls to nonamp version

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, amp-html

I need to recover AMP Urls after switching off Google AMP. Can you help me please for having 301 redirects on any AMP url back to NonAMP Version?

Example:

```
anydomain/hardware/heute-ist-putztag/amp
```

back to

```
anydomain/hardware/heute-ist-putztag
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove amp; from url with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460924/remove-amp-from-url-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a solution at myself

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/amp$ $1 [R=301,L]
```